# Limit of sequence $a_{0} \in (0,1)$, $a_{n+1} = \mu a_{n}(1-a_{n})$, $\mu \in (1,3)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm considering the sequence $a_{0} \in (0,1)$, $a_{n+1} = \mu a_{n}(1-a_{n})$, where $\mu \in (1,3)$ is a constant. I found that the fixed points of the function $f(x) = \mu x (1-x)$ are $0$ and $1-\frac{1}{\mu}$ and by drawing a lot of examples, I've concluded that the limit is generally $1-\frac{1}{\mu}$. However, I haven't been able to prove this.

I know that IF a limit exists, then by letting $n \to \infty$ in $a_{n+1} = \mu a_{n}(1-a_{n})$, it must be $0$ or $1-\frac{1}{\mu}$. I've tried to prove that in some cases the sequence is increasing and in others, decreasing, but the situation gets much too messy to be useful.

Is there a nice way to show that, for whichever choice of $a_{0}$, this sequence converges?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Behavior_dependent_on_r

Comment: $f(x)=\mu x(1-x) \Rightarrow f'(x)=\mu (1-2x)$ and $\left|f'\left(1-\frac{1}{\mu}\right)\right|=|2-\mu|<1$. This makes $x=1-\frac{1}{\mu}$ an [attractive fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attractive_fixed_points). Finding attraction interval is not so easy though.

Comment: @lhf is there a proof of the claim:
With r between 1 and 2, the population will quickly approach the value r − 1/r, independent of the initial population.
With r between 2 and 3, the population will also eventually approach the same value r − 1/r, but first will fluctuate around that value for some time. The rate of convergence is linear, except for r = 3, when it is dramatically slow, less than linear (see Bifurcation memory).

Comment: You can also try to look at the problem from the conjugate functions perspective. For example $\varphi(x)=-\mu x+\frac{\mu}{2}$ and $g(x)=x^2+\frac{\mu}{2}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{2}\right)$. It is easy to see that $f(x)=\varphi^{-1}\circ g \circ\varphi$ and $a_n=f^{\circ n}(a_0)=(\varphi^{-1}\circ g^{\circ n} \circ\varphi)(a_0)$.

Comment: If I were to rephrase the question as: find the set of non-wandering points of this dynamical system, would it be easier to look at $g$ instead of $f$? Where, of course, $f(x)=\mu x (1-x)$.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, looking at $g$ is always easier than looking at $f$. $\varphi$ is just a linear transformation. You will notice that $g\left(1-\frac{\mu}{2}\right)=1-\frac{\mu}{2}$ a fixed point for $g(x)$.

Comment: [This book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Iteration-Rational-Functions-Dynamical-Mathematics/dp/0387951512/) covers such tricks and a lot more.

Comment: I've been looking through this book, and it's great, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. My main goal is to find the topological entropy of $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $f(x)=\mu x (1-x)$ for $\mu \in (1,3)$. Is there a book which treats the logistic map mathematically, for various parameters $\mu$? I found a lot of links which claim that $a_{n} \to 1-\frac{1}{\mu}$ on the internet, but none actually prove it. Are there any "serious" mathematical references on the logistic map that you know of, for $\mu \in (1,3)"?

Comment: Function $f$ is closely related to $g$ via conjugacy. Iterations of the function $g(z)=z^2+c$ (in this case $c=\frac{\mu}{2}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{2}\right)$) are well studied (in the book I mentioned, page 14 ... page 27 [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dcheragh/Research/CourseNotes.pdf)). You may have different results for different $a_0$, that's what you have to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = a_n -(1-\frac{1}{\mu})$. Then the recurence for $x_n$ is $$ x_{n+1} = -\mu x_n^2 + x_n(2-\mu)$$
$$\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|} = |2 - \mu - \mu x_n| \le |2-\mu| + \mu|x_n|$$
For $\mu\in(1,3)$, $|2-\mu|<1$. So you only need to prove that at some point $|x_n| < \frac{1-|2-\mu|}{\mu}$, so that $|2-\mu| + \mu|x_n| < 1$, and from that point on $|x_n|$ will be monotonically decreasing (approximately geometrically), and will tend to $0$, that is $a_n$ will tend to $1-\frac{1}{\mu}$.

Comment: $|x_{n}|<\frac{1-|2-\mu|}{\mu}$ is a pretty strong condition for $\mu$ close to $3$ or close to $1$. Do you know of any references on the logistic map for $\mu \in (1,3)$?

Comment: I know no references. But it doesn't surprise me that $\mu\approx 1$ and $\mu \approx 3$ are problematic. First is $0\approx 1-\frac{1}{\mu}$ so the two stable points get close together; the other is a point of bifurcation.